# Design a commutative injective function between any (restricted) infinite set and unordered pairs thereof

Tags: code-golf, math, open-ended-function

[Related, but this only requires positive integers and does not have to be commutative](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8892/59487)

The Cantor Pairing Function is described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function). Essentially, it is an operation such that when it is applied to two values X and Y, one can obtain the original values X and Y given the result.

Your task is to design two functions: one which performs `X, Y -> Z` and the other which performs `Z -> X, Y`. Here's the catch: `X, Y -> Z` must be commutative. This means that `Z -> X, Y` won't be able to determine if the input was `X, Y` or `Y, X`.

The formal definition of this challenge would be:

Choose an countable infinite set S of numbers.
Design two functions that perform the following tasks:

- Given an unordered pair of values in S, return a value in S
- Given a return value from the initial function, return the unordered pair of values which evaluates to the input integer when passed through the first function. I don't care about the behaviour of this inverse function if the input isn't a return value from the first function.

## Requirements

- The result should be identical between runs.
- `{a, a}` is an unordered pair

Note: your answer is more likely to get an upvote from me if you provide a proof, but I will test answers when I get to it and upvote it once I'm fairly sure it works.

Comment: Doesn't this fit better for https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Jakube Not necessarily, as you are required to write code.

Comment: I'm assuming pairs are unique, but the numbers used in those pairs are not? So when `1,2` is one of the pairs, `1,3` can also be a potential pair (both use `1`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @Giuseppe The inverse does not need to be able to return the correct order; it's just that for function `f` and its inverse `g`, `sorted((x, y))` should be the same as `sorted(g(f(x, y)))`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino gotcha. That makes sense now.

Comment: Can we return a delimited string containing X & Y for the second function?

Comment: All answers so far appear to have assumed that *{a, a}* is an unordered pair, yet some definitions don't allow the members to be equal. Could you clarify?

Comment: Can the two functions share code?

Comment: @xnor I'm going to say that the two programs must be independent; that is, they can run on their own. Shared code would then have to be counted twice

Comment: does the function have to be a bijection? the title says so, but I don't see this requirement in the question, just injective.

Comment: @proudhaskeller I should remove `bijection` since `commutative bijection` is a contradiction. Yes, just injective. Thanks.

Comment: @Shaggy If that's approved by meta as a way of outputting a pair/tuple of numbers, then sure. If it's obvious what the two numbers are, that's fine.

Comment: @Dennis Um yes I should have specified; `{a, a}` is an unordered pair

Comment: If the pair-to-value function isn't required to be surjective, maybe "Given a value in S" could say "Given a return value from the first function"?  And maybe clarify whether it's okay for the value-to-pair function to output anything including pairs of elements of S, crash, etc. if its input is not a possible output of the pair-to-value function?

Comment: @aschepler Sure, I'll add something and if you want more clarified I'll add more. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 + 30 = 95 bytes

```hs
a#b=length.fst$span(<(max a b,min a b))[(a,b)|a<-[1..],b<-[1..a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yTYnNS@9JEMvrbhEpbggMU/DRiM3sUIhUSFJJzczD0RrakZrJOokadYk2uhGG@rpxeokQRiJsbH/cxOBimwVUvK5FAqKMvNKFFQUTJWNERxjZdP/AA)

```hs
([(a,b)|a<-[1..],b<-[1..a]]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzXyNaI1EnSbMm0UY32lBPL1YnCcJIjI1VVNT8n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCikK5gaPT/X3JaTmJ68X/d5IICAA)

---

**Note:** When the two functions may share code, this is only 75 bytes:

```hs
(l!!)
a#b=length.fst$span(<(max a b,min a b))l
l=[(a,b)|a<-[1..],b<-[1..a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcixDsIgEIDhnae4ph24hJKYplt5kspw1EIbDyTSwcFnFzVOTv@Xf6NyXZmrN7JFEcy5Sm4aFGxmScrhk6Z@PmltlfuBrBXUOsNrCsemfTm6kinJSUZ6AIFTcU/fInKN9LGBy01Avu/pgA6C9DDCgP9ngBHra/FModR@yfkN) The domain is the positive integers. The function `(#)` performs the pairing, the function `(l!!)` its inverse. Usage example: Both `(#) 5 3` and `(#) 3 5` yield `12`, and `(l!!) 12` yields `(5,3)`.

This works by explicitly listing all sorted pairs in an infinite list `l`:

```hs
l = [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(6,1), ...`
```

The encoding is then just the index in this list.

Comment: by the OP, shared code must be counted twice

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 + 6 = 14 bytes

```
ij\aSQ16
```

```
    SQ   # Sort the input
 j\a     # join with "a"
i     16 # convert from base 16 to base 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzMrJjE40NDs/38jcx1LIwA)

```
c.HQ\a
```

```
 .HQ     # convert from base 10 to 16
c   \a   # split on "a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1nPIzAm8f9/QzMjE1MDAA)
Domain: Positive integers.

Comment: nice approach! +1

Comment: Doesn't work for a lot of numbers like `2` and `10` for example (which are in the domain)

Comment: Sure. [Example1](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1nPIzAm8f9/QyMA), [Example2](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1nPIzAm8f9/QwMA)

Comment: The 2nd function is supposed to work for _any_ value in S, not just one that was generated with the first function (I made the same mistake).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 + 11 = 19 bytes

Rolled back since Rod's algorithm didn't work.

This works on the domain of the positive integers.

Takes `x` and `y` as 2 arguments, doesn't matter in which order, returns `z`.

```
»’RSð+ð«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//wrvigJlSU8OwK8Owwqv///8z/zE)

Takes `z` and returns `[min(x, y), max(x, y)]`

```
R€Ẏ,Rx`$ị@€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/oUdOah7v6dIIqElQe7u52AHL///9vAgA)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This isn't Rod's algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 + 39 = 75 bytes

Thanks to @tsh for saving two bytes.

The domain is non-negative integers.

```c
p(x,y){return y>x?p(y,x):-~x*x/2+y;}
```

Takes `x` and `y`, returns `z`.

```c
u(int*r){for(*r=0;r[1]>*r;r[1]-=++*r);}
```

Takes a two-element `int` array. The second element must be set to `z` before the call. After the call `r` contains `x` and `y`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDBaoQwFEXX@hWXKUJiYusI3TRqP8S6KGamFdqMpAqJkv66fZHpIsnjHu6Bl6H4GIZ9n5iTnm/2Mi/WwLfudWJeOv5S/LrcPVXCq7Cw0cy55dv1Zllum1LZ7ty3uT3eohGCoAr7w2iGr0VfUP/Merw9frYpFfH9PhrGsaUJ9RFdWMmBtX6OtxAHS2Juu6pHgw2lxIqgKF4Yue/YEbNd2Uv4Yzr3kUyW2JWdWKYlMs1RFy2ySv@fN3OScNQhp0RcGJ7HgQLHozykyf0DSpWG/Q8)

Comment: `(x+1)` -> `-~x`

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES7), 44 bytes

```
(x,y)=>x>y?x*x+y:y*y+x
z=>[x=z**.5|0,y=z-x*x]
```

Maps from non-negative integers to a subset thereof.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

#### pair of positive integers to positive integer, 5 bytes

```
Ṁc2+Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoZkI@2HO5v@//9vaK6jYGQMAA)

#### positive integer to pair of positive integers, 6 bytes

```
ŒċṀÞị@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCPdD3c2HJ73cHe3w////43MDQA)

### Algorithm

If we sort the set of all unordered pairs of positive integers by their maximum and then by their sum, we get the following sequence.

**{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {3,3}, {1,4}, {2,4}, {3,4}, {4,4}, {1,5}, {2,5}, {3,5}, {4,5}, {5,5}, …**

The first function takes a pair **{x,y}** and finds its index in this sequence.

The second function takes a positive integer **z** and returns the **z**<sup>th</sup> item of the sequence.

Note that this mapping is the same as in [@EriktheOutgolfer's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142387/12012).

### How it works

```
Ṁc2+Ṃ   Main link. Argument: [x, y]
        Let m = max(x, y) and n = min(x, y).

Ṁ       Maximum; yield m.
 c2     2-combinations; yield mC2 = m(m-1)/2.
        Note that there's one pair with maximum 1 ({1,1}), two pairs with maximum 2
        ({1,2}, {2,2}), etc., so there are 1 + 2 + … + (m-1) = m(m-1)/2 pairs with
        maximum less than m.
    Ṃ   Minimum; yield n.
        Note that {x,y} is the n-th pair with maximum m.
   +    Add; yield mC2 + n.
        This finds {x,y}'s index in the sequence.
```

```
ŒċṀÞị@  Main link. Argument: z

Œċ      2-combinations w/replacement; yield all pairs [x, y] such that x ≤ y ≤ z.
  ṀÞ    Sort by maximum.
    ị@  Retrieve the pair at index z (1-based).
```

Comment: Explanation please. I'm not confident this is valid...

Comment: I've added the algorithm.

Comment: Something doesn't stick well to me...although I'm not sure if this is invalid either. Basically it kind of doesn't stick well that you use both `c` and `Œċ`...although I may be wrong. BTW that was my answer that you outgolfed >_>

Comment: The difference is minimal for pairs. If **C** computes combinations without replacement and **Ƈ** computes combinations with, **nƇ2 = nC2 + n**.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica (35+53)=78 Bytes

```
((x=Min[#])+(y=Max[#]))(x+y+1)/2+y&

(i=Floor[(-1+Sqrt[1+8#])/2];{#-i(1+i)/2,i(3+i)/2-#})&
```

This is the one good known quadratic pairing function for Z<-->ZxZ combined with Min and Max to make it orderless.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>153</s> <s>146</s> <s>141</s> 137 + <s>268</s> <s>224</s> <s>216</s> 205 bytes

Pair function

```
a->{String f="";for(int i=(f+a[0]).length(),c=0,j;i>0;i-=c,f+=c,c=0)for(j=1;j<10;c+=i-j++<0?0:1);return new Integer(a[0]+""+a[1]+"0"+f);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU@xboMwEJ3LV5yY7BosI7VLHKdbpQ6dMiIGFwy1SwwyR6oo4tup01KpveHu9PTuvXtOn3U@jMa75mO1p3EICC5ifEbb83b2NdrB83uZJOP81tsa6l5PE7xq6@Ga3G3ghBrjeN74@xePpjOhrDLY1gM0oGDV@eF6xGB9B61KU9kOgViPYBVpmS5FRXlvfIfvhGa1EpmT9iCkzVWdtSy2iNHbjVOFdPtCyJopmzvG9uJJ7Aoqg8E5ePDm89eZ3GRZmkb5Ik6RspbKZZUQK7m1/xnOg23gFOORnz/LCnToJhrTwlbHy4TmxIcZ@Rgp2HvScD2O/YX88S2rayFE9viwUCq/b5dkWb8A)

Depair function

```
r->{String a=r+"",t=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf('0')+1);int l=0,i=l,o=t.length();for(;i<o;l+=r.decode(t.charAt(i++)+""));return new int[]{r.decode(a.substring(0,l)),r.decode(a.substring(l,a.length()-o-1))};}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVA9a8MwEJ3rX3F4iVTLwqbtpDjQpZChdMhoPCi24ihVJCOf04bg3@4qH4QWesMJ3j29d/d28iBT1ym7az4nve@cR9gFjA@oDd8MtkbtLH8UUdQNa6NrqI3se3iX2sIperiBPUoMz9uNP19aVK3yDLTFslqAggImny5OK/TatiALn8Qxw0Lyflj3F5BIHqRxaRv1/bEhs2xGk5yKoACmyJguDHMFcqNsi1tCxcZ5IvTcCZMUnjeqdo0iyOut9K9IdJLQYEGp8AoHb8Gqr@s2pzv5t3nGDKXs35Fh8u6aujSndBTjJCBUdG5/Mzg43cA@xEOut5YVSN/29JzWxR9kCENx2XXmSPIse3nOnqi4KJ1rdexR7bkbkHfhPxpLZJlVkEDM4tBlmVc3@hiN0w8)

Comment: You can golf a few parts. In the pair function: `int i=(""+a[0]).length()` can be `int i=(f+a[0]).length()`; the space between `c=0,j;i>0;` can be removed; `a[0].parseInt` can be `new Integer`. In the depair function: all three `r.parseInt` can be `r.decode`; and you could make an int variable for `t.length()`, since you use it twice.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 66 bytes

```
f=->x,y{2**~-x|2**~-y}
g=->n{x,y=(1..n).select{|i|n[i-1]>0};[x,y||x]}
```

I'm trying to find a way to cunningly select an infinite set to make this easier, this is the best I've got so far.

We define f(x,y) = 2<sup>x-1</sup> bitwise-or 2<sup>y-1</sup>. The domain consists of the set defined recursively as containing 1,2, and all numbers that can be produced by calling f on numbers in the set (note that f(1,1) = 1 and f(2,2) = 2, so 1 and 2 have inverses). The resulting numbers all have either one or two 1s in their binary expansion, with the indices of the 1s corresponding to numbers in the set. We can get the original unordered pair out by taking the indices. If there's only one 1, that means the elements of the pair are equal.

For example, f(3,5) is 20, because 20 is 10100 in base 2, which has 1s in the 3rd and 5th least significant places.

Comment: S=[this set (OEIS link)](http://oeis.org/A048645)

Comment: Thanks, S is actually a subset of that OEIS sequence though because it only includes numbers whose 1s have indexes in S.

Comment: ah yes, of course. Well, no other sequence matches the first few terms (up to 32).

Comment: Add 0 to S and you can save a few decrements.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 + 11 = 17 bytes

Port of my Jelly answer.

Domain: positive integers.

Takes a list `[x, y]` as input, returns `z`.

```
{`<LO+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/OsHGx1/7//9oQx0F41gA)

Takes a positive integer `z` as input, returns `[min(x, y), max(x, y)]`.

```
L2ã€{RÙR¹<è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx@jw4kdNa6qDDs8MOrTT5vCK//9NAA)

-5 thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna).

Comment: Your second program can save 5 bytes with [L2ã€{RÙRI<è](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx@jw4kdNa6qDDs8M8rQ5vOL/fxMA)

Comment: @Emigna Nice trick with `2ã€{RÙR`!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 72 bytes

```
f=a=>eval('0x'+a.sort().join`a`)
g=n=>n.toString(16).split`a`.map(x=>+x)
```

Works for positive integers (in theory). Quite simple idea: sort two number in some (magic) order, connect them as string by a letter `"a"`, parse it as hex integer.

```js
f=a=>eval('0x'+a.sort().join`a`)
g=n=>n.toString(16).split`a`.map(x=>+x)
```

```html
<pre oninput="p.value=f([+x.value, +y.value])">
     X = <input id="x" type="number" min="0" />
     Y = <input id="y" type="number" min="0" />
 f(X,Y)= <output id="p"></output>
</pre>

<pre oninput="q.value=g(+u.value).join(', ')">
     U = <input id="u" type="number" />
   g(U)= <output id="q"></output>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 6+8=14 bytes

Encoding function, takes two inputs n, m. Outputs product of nth prime and mth prime.

```
,iYq]*
```

Steps:

- `,`  - Do twice
- `i`  - Push input
- `Yq` - Pop input, push input'th prime
- `]*` - End do twice, pop both primes and push product

---

Decoding function, takes one input m. Outputs the number of primes below each of the prime factors of n.

```
iYf"@Zqn
```

Steps:

- `i` - Push input
- `Yf` - Pop input, push array of prime factors
- `"` - For n in array
- `@Zq` - Push array of primes below n
- `n` - Pop array, push length of array

This is commutative because multiplication is commutative, and injective because prime factorizations are unique. Not that this is not onto the integers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5+3=8 bytes

I really hope I got the challenge right, I see some deleted answers that seem valid to me...

Couples of positive integers to a single positive integer:

```
¤*!İp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ASLcUjGwr@//9v/N8IAA)

It works by taking the numbers at the given indices (1-indexed) from the list of prime numbers, and multiplying them.

Result of the first function to couples of positive integers:

```
mṗp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fhzukF////NzQFAA)

We factorize the input number and return the index in the list of primes of all (both) of its factors.

#### Worked example

Given `(4,1)` as a starting couple, we take the fourth and first prime numbers `(7,2)` and multiply them → `14`. This multiplication is what makes the function indipendent on the order of the two elements.

Starting from `14`, we factorize it `(2,7)` and return the indices of `2` and `7` in the list of prime numbers → `(1,4)`.

Comment: Actually, looking at the deleted answer from Arnauld, its algorithm is even better, and porting it to Husk would result in 6 bytes... Could someone confirm whether its solution (and mine too) is valid or not?

Comment: Doesn't work for primes (which are in the domain of positive integers)

Comment: @Emigna the second function doesn't, but primes are never returned by the first one...

Comment: Your domain is positive integers, so both methods need to work for positive integers. EDIT: or at least that used to be a requirement. The current rules seem to allow a subset of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/762f6e301f0ea55178a4e121663c1c68), 80 bytes ( 38 + 42 )

---

#### Data

#### Encoder

- **Input** `Int32` `l` A number
- **Input** `Int32` `r` A number
- **Output** `Int64` Both ints fused together

#### Decoder

- **Input** `Int32` `v` The value
- **Output** `Int32[]` An array with the two original ints.

---

#### Golfed

```cs
// Encoder
e=(l,r)=>{return(long)l<<32|(uint)r;};

// Decoder
d=v=>{return new[]{v>>32,v&0xFFFFFFFFL};};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
// Encoder
e = ( l, r ) => {
    return (long) l << 32 | (uint) r;
};

// Decoder
d = v => {
    return new[] {
        v >> 32,
        v & 0xFFFFFFFFL };
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Encoder
// Takes a pair of ints
e = ( l, r ) => {

    // Returns the ints fused together in a long where the first 32 bits are the first int
    // and the last 32 bits the second int
    return (long) l << 32 | (uint) r;
};

// Decoder
// Takes a long
d = v => {

    // Returns an array with the ints decoded where...
    return new[] {
    
        // ... the first 32 bits are the first int...
        v >> 32,
        
        // ... and the last 32 bits the second int
        v & 0xFFFFFFFFL };
};
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestBench {
    public class Program {
        // Methods
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Func<Int32, Int32, Int64> e = ( l, r ) => {
                return(long) l << 32 | (uint) r;
            };
            Func<Int64, Int64[]> d = v => {
                return new[] { v >> 32, v & 0xFFFFFFFFL };
            };

            List<KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>>
                testCases = new List<KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>>() {
                    new KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>( 13, 897 ),
                    new KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>( 54234, 0 ),
                    new KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>( 0, 0 ),
                    new KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>( 1, 1 ),
                    new KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>( 615234, 1223343 ),
                };

            foreach( KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32> testCase in testCases ) {
                Console.WriteLine( $" ENCODER: {testCase.Key}, {testCase.Value} = {e( testCase.Key, testCase.Value )}" );
                Console.Write( $"DECODING: {e( testCase.Key, testCase.Value )} = " );
                PrintArray( d( e( testCase.Key, testCase.Value ) ) );

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void PrintArray<TSource>( TSource[] array ) {
            PrintArray( array, o => o.ToString() );
        }
        public static void PrintArray<TSource>( TSource[] array, Func<TSource, String> valueFetcher ) {
            List<String>
                output = new List<String>();

            for( Int32 index = 0; index < array.Length; index++ ) {
                output.Add( valueFetcher( array[ index ] ) );
            }

            Console.WriteLine( $"[ {String.Join( ", ", output )} ]" );
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `80 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Answer (score 0):

## Python: 41+45=86

### encoder: 41

```
e=lambda*x:int('1'*max(x)+'0'+'1'*min(x))
```

> ```
> e(4, 3), e(3,4)
> ```
>
> (11110111, 11110111)

### decoder: 45

```
d=lambda z:[len(i)for i in str(z).split('0')]
```

> ```
> d(11110111)
> ```
>
> [4, 3]

## Older attempt:

Python: 114: 30 + 84

### encoder: 30

accepts 2 integers, returns a string

```
e=lambda*x:2**max(x)*3**min(x)
```

> ```
> e(3, 4), e(4, 3)
> ```
>
> (432, 432)

### decoder: 86

```
def d(z):
 x=y=0
 while 1-z%2:
  x+=1
  z/=2
 while 1-z%3:
  y+=1
  z/=3
 return x,y
```

> ```
> d(432)
> ```
>
> 4, 3

### decoder2: 120

another attempt with generator comprehensions and sum

```
def d(z):
 x=sum(1 for i in range(z)if not z%(2**i))-1
 z/=2**x
 return x,sum(1 for i in range(int(z))if not z%(3**i))-1
```

Comment: based on second attempt: `e=lambda*x:10**sum(x)-10**min(x);d=lambda z:map(`z`.count,'09')`; [TIO](https://tio.run/##bcpBDsIgEIXhPadg1xlSTSXd2KRnsQM0kUSmpEKsvTzSRHfuvvzvxXe6L6xLmccHBeNIbcOlU@qZA2x4Ohg8Vwr3Pch9CBRh2qezXTKntumuDRaSo/ScYKXXzXPMCRCF@RdtjTNQKw2KuB6z/cFVYtG96PUH)

Comment: @tsh very nice. I will adapt it later, or you can submit your own answer