# (Σ*)² ⟲ Σ* (aka Round-Trip a String Pair)

Tags: string, popularity-contest

This is a challenge I thought of recently which I think is not hard but allows for a wide range of possible solutions. Seems like a perfect fit for the creativity of PPCG users :)

### Your Task

Define two functions which together form a lossless round-trip `String × String → String → String × String`.

More specifically, define two functions `combine` and `separate` with repsective types `String × String → String` and `String → String × String` such that `separate ∘ combine = id`.

Even more specifically, define two functions (or methods/procedures/etc), which I will refer to as `combine` and `separate`, and which exhibit the following characteristics:

- When invoked with a single string, `separate` produces two strings as results. (You may use any reasonable string type. Most languages don't canonically allow producing multiple values, so feel free to to do something equivalent, such as returning a 2-tuple or modifying two global variables.)
- When invoked with two strings, `combine` produces a single string as result. (You may accept input to `separate` in the same form that `combine` produces, or any other reasonable form.)
- For any two strings `a` and `b`, `separate(combine(a, b))` must result in two strings which are (structurally) equivalent to `a` and `b`.
- The above bullets are the *only* restrictions on `combine` and `separate`. So, for instance, `combine ∘ separate` need not be `id`, and `separate` can even be a partial function, if you like.

(Defer to the final and more-verbose description if there are any ambiguities between the three)

### Intent

My goal with this challenge is to inspire creative and interesting solutions. As such, in order to avoid priming/suggesting your thinking about how to solve this problem, I will not be providing test cases, and I **strongly** suggest that you do not look at the existing answers until you submit your own.

### Winning Criteria

This challenge is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest); the answer with the highest score at noon on April 5th, UTC, is the winner.

Guidelines for voters, included to be a valid [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), are as follows:

- Strongly prefer answers which you do not immediately comprehend, are not obviously correct, and/or surprise you
- Prefer answers which go beyond strings, i.e., those which make use of more than the problem statement did (functions, strings, pairs)
- Avoid answers which are similar to your own solution(s)
- Avoid answers which boil down to language builtins

---

Have fun!

Comment: Should `combine ∘ separate` also be an identity function?

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI It need not be, but you may make it so if you like

Comment: I've voted to close this as lacking an *objective* winning criteria. [Popularity contests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info) need clear rules about *what* voters should be looking for, rather than just specifying a task and saying "Do this, but creatively". The fact that [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222561/66833) boring answer currently has a score of +3 means that either the voting on this challenge is too subjective, or voters aren't following your intent well enough for this to remain open

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly If popularity contests require a winning criteria besides popularity, then I don't understand the point of the category. But that is a question for elsewhere. Truth is, I don't have another winning criteria; I just wanted to share what I think is an interesting challenge that can inspire creativity and that people will enjoy. I thought popularity-contest would be the right tag for that. Is there another?

Comment: Pop-cons have been a divisive topic here for a long time (basically since the site began). We've generally come to the consensus that in order to meet our "objective winning criteria" standards that we hold all challenges to, they need a clear and objective guide for voters, detailing what (broadly) should and shouldn't be upvoted. Questions which have the form "Do X creatively" rarely fit this criteria, and pop-cons are often a "trap" for less experienced challenge authors. I'm sorry I didn't see this question in the Sandbox, I would've warned against it there

Comment: I will see if perhaps I can think up some voting guidelines that could retain the spirit of the post.

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly I have added some criterion. Let me know if it is still insufficient.

Comment: @Quelklef Unfortunately the pop-con tag is now [largely a trap for beginners](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8134), even more so than 5 years ago when I wrote that post. Part of the reason they became disfavored is that votes have been poor at selecting the best answers, with [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and [bias for trivial answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13128). Even explicit voting guidelines like you gave tend to [get ignored in practice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111092).

Comment: @Quelklef I'm sorry the Sandbox was really unhelpful here. I see that you [Sandboxed this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20924/20260), leaving it for four days and getting two upvotes, but nobody said anything about popularity contests or left any comments. If I'd read it, I'd have strongly suggested changing it to [tag:code-golf] and still do now. I find that a lot of interesting unexpected approaches come out of trying to shorten code, by getting to the heart of the algorithm and playing to the strengths of each particular language.

Comment: Related questions: [Bijection between binary strings and pairs thereof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/bijection-between-binary-strings-and-pairs-thereof/8905), [Injection from two strings to one string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193640/injection-from-two-strings-to-one-string), [Surjection from one string to two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194478/surjection-from-one-string-to-two-strings).

Comment: @xnor I appreciate the feedback. I considered making it code-golf originally, but had predicted that doing so would mostly inspire solutions like `combine = toJSON; separate = fromJSON`. However, it sounds like you are suggesting that I may be pleasantly surprised. Since this question is now closed, I think bringing it back as a code-golf is probably the best option. (Would that best be done by editing this post or making a new one?)

Comment: Are we allowed to exclude certain characters those allowed by the strings?  Eg, newlines or spaces?

Comment: @Jonah Nope. The algorithm must work on *all* `(string, string)` pairs. (The problem is, I think, uninteresting otherwise)

Comment: @Quelklef Actually on second look, I'm afraid you're probably right about code golf for this giving mostly boring solutions, as evidenced by the the now-deleted first answer here and many of the answers to [Injection from two strings to one string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193640/20260). Also, a code golf adaptation might be too similar to that challenge, without much new coming from requiring the round-trip back to part of the byte count. So I don't really know what to suggest. Might requiring a bijection possibly make for more varied solutions?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is extra credit, but your problem got me thinking a lot about this and what interested me the most was not just `separate` being the left inverse of `combine`, but having them be true inverses of each other. This ends up with us defining a bijection from `String -> String x String`. The path I took was as follows

- Define a bijection from `String -> N`
- Define a bijection from `N -> N x N`
- Combine them to get the functions we need

#### String -> N

Let `r` be the size of the character set you're working with and give each character a unique value from 1 to `r`, say `f(c) = n`. Going from right to left and indexing starting from zero, create the number `f(s[0])r^0 + f(s[1])r^1 + f(s[2])r^2 ... f(s[length(s)])r^(length(s))`. The lowest number you can get this way is 1, so we let the empty string equal 0.

#### N -> N x N

Take `n` in any base you like. Separate even digits into one part of the tuple and the odd digits into the other to make a pair of numbers. E.g. `12345 -> (24, 135)`. To work your way back, combine the numbers in the opposite way, inserting extra zeros as necessary.

#### Putting it all together

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/)

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Function ((&))
-- tio is saying this isn't correct for some reason so gotta define it manually
-- import Data.Functor ((<&>))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ separate "Hello, world!"
  putStrLn $ combine ("Hello, world!", "")
  putStrLn $ show $ separate $ combine ("Hello, world!", "")
  putStrLn $ combine $ separate "Hello, world!" 

separate :: String -> (String, String)
separate str =
  str
  <&> toInt
  & fromNZ
  & split
  & tmap toNZ
  & tmap (map fromInt)

combine :: (String, String) -> String
combine strs =
  strs
  & tmap (map toInt)
  & tmap fromNZ
  & join
  & toNZ
  <&> fromInt

base :: Int
base = 95

toInt :: Char -> Int
toInt c = fromEnum c - 31

fromInt :: Int -> Char
fromInt i = toEnum $ i + 31

strip :: [Int] -> [Int]
strip is = case is of
  0 : i : tail -> strip $ i : tail
  _ -> is

split :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
split =
  tmap strip . fst . foldr
    (\a ((acc1, acc0), i) ->
      (if mod i 2 == 0 then
        (acc1, a : acc0)
      else
        (a : acc1, acc0)
      , i + 1
      )
    )
    (([], []), 0)

join :: ([Int], [Int]) -> [Int]
join (l1, l2)= strip $ reverse $ go [] (reverse l1, reverse l2)
  where
    go :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int]) -> [Int]
    go acc (l1', l2') = case (l1', l2') of
      (head1 : tail1, head2 : tail2) -> head2 : head1 : go acc (tail1, tail2)
      ([], head : tail) -> head : 0 : go acc ([], tail)
      (head : tail, []) -> 0 : head : go acc (tail, [])
      ([], []) ->  acc

tmap :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
tmap f (a1, a2) = (f a1, f a2)

fromNZ :: [Int] -> [Int]
fromNZ is =
  if is == [] then [0]
  else let
    (result, finalCarry) =
      foldr
        (\i' (acc, carry) ->
          let
            i =
              if carry then i' + 1
              else i'
          in
            if i >= base then (i - base : acc, True)
            else (i : acc, False)
        )
        ([], False)
        is
  in
    if finalCarry then 1 : result
    else result

toNZ :: [Int] -> [Int]
toNZ is =
  if is == [0] then []
  else let
    (result, finalUncarry) =
      foldr
        (\i' (acc, uncarry) ->
          let
            i =
              if uncarry then i' - 1
              else i'
          in
            if i <= 0 then (i + base : acc, True)
            else (i : acc, False)
        )
        ([], False)
        is
  in
    if finalUncarry then
      case result of
        a : tail ->
          if a == base then tail
          else result
        _ -> result
    else result

m <&> f = f <$> m
infixl 1 <&>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVVNbxw3DL3rVzCG4dXAs8Z6gx5qeHxxGzRAkx6aXOIahTyr8SqdkRaSto5/vUNSmo9d223iQ@YwI5KP5BNJadYq/KPb9uGhc6ttq@GdMhbu1tprIUy3cT7CLyqqkzdbW0fjLEh5VBRiPgeUwAQI6t7YW4hrXJtgZxFq572uIzTOQ3CdBq9VQM/g4NbFqGClG2M1mAidslvVtvcU71E2dJfy/OgC04mOaJ2dwds/QBZJqmDlBMBmG/@M/ncLhxDW7o4@eqO8ihoOfsOduRLunG9Xrw52wbXrboiF3EOVcHBQ/Hfc73Luoc/zAiEGE24RHamg8wuQaVlmVTHCQvRQYR784htrBNG9tRHXR9B4173/xMuwaU1Sxk5tEJP1LEl6ERgdscI9T2Swn5e4pOWAwsShZxD2YjKVYlROCH12xiZDokLMMwUhblTg9CTwuoKffxKCw5H@cq08USF7UtYIIfdf7bZDYQ6vT4XI8XIkciDHQW3QJzr2OEThmH1wF2ZDHlcIuSYfXmQ9TnYFNTHClWuQ9wLO0PcMojItoRPucNAh5G/Sm4CxqQk7sSWvyqQoMoCKyeVKsU6gCZHerl1RjwHkXwrPg6rr0xLwvShKMNQaNqLZNIBnGCksoaqQYVxrm21ozX7Ij32zQbdBTzDJ2sfPhpKrdJqlpE1vKa9oF9fIBNGCmsvjs7O9sZhsly2Gb5dFNdTM63@1D3RAbh0GA9krCDmsl5Qy3UuUGqHPV3RMmaG4HUo8o8yzom/mRMNN5S2ttVqd5i5ifhKXWVxy4F7TA/vw2SEB@2hUHwLmCEMAlBcTX4Kxfcoi@3CByW@Rk@7lZPs0X4YTAg8PTRT1RJHuhi1SYYPT6qZEXQI1qKfOL6k@sgESGhLTiXr/6YnjkQ0mXQU4gLSqqIk0fHC1oA7QjEGrYxoZr8O2jRjaWNVeKu/vC3amZ5z1NO9mxnNbYrsYN8w6PX3E/jFDmEHTJMdEBoONU9w/zM3MJlpjxV4MAxcV8H3EcaTBeyZdVcDkPvitLsSjqNL0gDcK5RExrrhde1ZDt2kmgcnHMqXsNHGphGLIlGVBd@oTTWL1oxYt@h79T4s@2vobm7S1L25Tdh0aNX9ho877e4@qf/yDu/RxsokM5GsmlXO8YoBv4fznEDs7UNSacdTyn2SH8KT59PBf5rmB6NL/lX6ScH54AZ0wtjFfWpwiNDw8fAU)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal)

Simply lists the code points in both strings. Within each string, code points are delimited with commas, and the two strings's code points are separated with a semicolon. The only gotcha is to ensure that empty strings decode to empty strings.

### Combine

```
⪫Ｅ²⪫ＥＳ℅λ,¦;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPwzexQMNIRwHO9swrKC0JLgEqSNfQ1FHwL0rJzEvM0cjRBHKUdJTAlDWQsv7/Pzk/NykzL5WrOLUgsSixJPW/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

### Separate

```
Ｅ⪪Ｓ;∧ι⭆⪪ι,℅Ｉλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwDIZfZfSUQYRFnFp6kp08CMKeoFTRQulKjb5@TN3BHPLxfwl/ePoaFp9ErjVmhosvMJcUGc65vHlmtQ/osTPO6D7lG0TsVv3/VWWw3Set84HvFSb/Ykj9b5yItUhESINFe1SMGgclOaKxUfMW7UGxW7FvVjaf9AU) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal)

Works by prefixing each character of the first string with a comma, suffixing each character of the second string with a comma, and then joining the strings with a semicolon. This simplifies decoding as there are an equal number of commas and original characters. There is a slight Charcoal gotcha in that it can't chop a zero-length string, so to obtains the first string the decoder chops the original string at the semicolon before stripping the commas (still one byte shorter than slicing though), while for the second string it can strip the commas first and then slice from where the semicolon used to be.

### Combine

```
⪫Ｅ²⭆Ｓ⎇ι⁺λ,⁺,λ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBCgIxDIXhvacIXSUQN27nBArCgF4glqKFmpZMR/D0scP4Vu/740ssVinus2XteKlZ8SoNTwy3PtJzw1nb2nciMdyTqdgXM8Nc1gULQ@BAf43LUGhs5CkQTe6xvh9Z02FJTUx68uOn/AA) Link is to verbose version of code.

### Separate

```
≔⌕Φθ¬﹪κ²;η⟦Φ…θ⊗η﹪κ²✂Φθ﹪κ²η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU29CsIwGNx9itApgXNxzSQVN6XgKA5pGkzwM19NU8Gnjyk4qMMdB/dnvUmWDZWynaZwjXIf4lCJskvyAXHkLA88zMTyBrFRSkE0uqnslV51KcQsz594@7LkWs/jUtzx3JMbpF8aPwsQJwrWfZ382V5dlC4FFow7egREOD3BYYRBqshVl/WT3g) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript

```js
const obfuscate = str => [...str].map(e=>e.charCodeAt(0).toString(36) + '?').join``;
const combine = (first, second) => obfuscate(first) + ' ' + obfuscate(second);
const separate = string => string.split(' ').map(x =>x.split('?').filter(b=>b).map(el => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(el, 36))).join``);
```

> In this case, `separate` is a partial function because it is only defined on specially formatted strings generated by `combine`. The `obfuscate` helper function turns the input string into an array of strings composed of the base-36 representation of the current character codepoint, plus a question mark. The array is then joined and returned. Then, `combine` returns the obfuscation of the first string, a space, then an obfuscation of a second string. `separate` undoes `obfuscate` on both strings and returns the array, in essence. Upon reading the answers, I found out that I sorta ported @Neil's answer with the difference being that I used a base-36 representation.

Answer (score 2):

Can't let @Mason have it for free (edit 1: also @Neil posted as I write this), so I'm dropping in with answer number 4 and 5 (edit 2: goddamn someone posted another answer): the *python convertors*.

## Answer One: the easy version

### (string conversion using split())

```python
import math
def combine(stringA, stringB):
  stringC = stringA + "\n" + stringB
  len1 = len(stringC)
  stringD = stringC * len1
  return stringD
def seperate(stringE):
  len2 = math.isqrt(len(stringE))
  stringF = stringE[0:len2]
  stringG, stringH = stringF.split("*", 2)
  return stringG, stringH
```

This functions takes two strings, combines them with an asterisk and then multiplies them by their combined length (plus the asterisk). To decode, it takes the square root of the length, splits ton the asterisk, and returns the strings (tested).

Now for the *hard* version.

## Answer Two: the actually hard version

### (hex conversion)

```python
def combine2(stringI, stringJ):
  stringK = stringI + "\n" + stringJ 
  integerA = stringK.encode().hex()
  integerB = int(integerA, 16)
  return integerB
def seperate2(integerC):
  integerD = (int(integerC))
  integerE = hex(integerD)
  stringL = str(integerE)
  stringM = stringL[2:]
  stringN = bytes.fromhex(stringM).decode('ascii')
  stringO, stringP = stringN.split(":")
  return stringO, stringP
```

Three years later and I've actually done it: this code can first convert a string to hex, return that, then take that hex string (note, leave the 0x in or the first character will be removed) and convert it to the string that you originally had (again, ***painfully*** tested).
(Edit 3: now you can't break it - newlines can't appear in input)

Comment: Are you sure this works if the strings to combine themselves contain asterisks?

Comment: If the second one has an asterisk, it will be preserved (note the clever use of the split("*", 2), preventing more than one split): the only issue I can see is if the first one has an asterisk. I'm not sure how you would go around that (same with the second one)

Comment: This is very interesting. What is the reason for repeating the string in the first solution? Also, as xnor and you have noticed, it seems that this will fail if the first string contains an asterisk. For the second solution, similar notes: what's the purpose of the hex encoding, and won't this fail if the first string contains a colon?

Comment: To answer your questions - 1) No reason, really, just because I thought it would be cooler. 2) Yes, it would fail if the first string contained a colon (or asterisk in the other code), but unfortunately, I don't think split() works with non-printable ascii characters.

Comment: For a solution to be valid, it technically must work for every possible string pair. If you want a valid solution, you're gonna have to get a little more clever ;)

Comment: Ok - I'll try and fix it in the morning

Comment: Fixed now. (hopefully)