# (Σ*)² ⟲ Σ* (Round-Trip a String Pair)

Tags: code-golf, string

[We're back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222560/43266)! And this time with an objective scoring criteria!

---

This is a challenge I thought of recently which I think is not hard but allows for a wide range of possible solutions. Seems like a perfect fit for the creativity of PPCG users :)

### Your Task

Define two functions `combine` and `separate` with respective types `String × String → String` and `String → String × String` such that `separate ∘ combine = id`.

More precisely, define two functions (or methods/procedures/etc), which I will refer to as `combine` and `separate`, and which exhibit the following characteristics:

- When invoked with a single string, `separate` produces two strings as results. (You may use any reasonable string type. Most languages don't canonically allow producing multiple values, so feel free to to do something equivalent, such as returning a 2-tuple or modifying two global variables.)
- When invoked with two strings, `combine` produces a single string as result. (You may accept input to `separate` in the same form that `combine` produces, or any other reasonable form.)
- For any two strings `a` and `b`, `separate(combine(a, b))` must result in two strings which are (structurally) equivalent to `a` and `b`.
- The above bullets are the *only* restrictions on `combine` and `separate`. So, for instance, `combine ∘ separate` need not be `id`, and `separate` can even be a partial function, if you like.
- The functions need not actually be named `combine` and `separate`

### Intent

My goal with this challenge is to inspire creative and interesting solutions. As such, in order to avoid priming/suggesting your thinking about how to solve this problem, I will not be providing test cases, and I **strongly** suggest that you do not look at the existing answers until you submit your own.

### Winning Criteria

This challenge is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); the answer with the lowest score wins. Score is defined as number of bytes, **except that it's -75% if** `combine ∘ separate = id` as well (i.e., if `combine` is bijective and `separate = combine⁻¹`).

For brownie points, also try making your solution, in principle,

- work on any alphabet rather than `char`, possibly including alphabets of size- 0, 1, or 2
- generalize nicely to \$n\$-tuples or lists

---

Have fun!

Comment: Note: [Bijection between binary strings and pairs thereof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8892/43266) is very similar to this question. However, that question requires a bijection and works on bitstrings. I feel that while using strings as opposed to bitstrings is mathematically inconsequential, it will give rise to different kinds of answers.

Comment: Also similar (originally from xnor): [Surjection from one string to two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194478/43266), [Injection from two strings to one string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193640/43266)

Comment: I'd suggest removing the deadline and just letting the challenge be open-ended. Additionally, see [Things to avoid when writing challenges: Bonuses](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/66833). Also, did you mean to remove the "Intent" section when copying over from the pop-con version?

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly Hey, thanks for the feedback. The "Intent" section is intentional (hah!), as that's still my goal with the challenge; it's just now in a code-golf format. The bonus is also intentional because I want to reward non-eval/repr solutions. Let me know if you think there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Also, I've removed the deadline, as you suggested

Comment: What is the default range of individual characters in a string?

Comment: @Bubbler As in, what characters are included in `char`?

Comment: @Quelklef Yes. In the current state, it could be printable ASCII, whole Unicode, a language's code page, or whatever you can think of. (Also, handling alphabet of size 1 is very different from handling alphabet of size 2 or greater)

Comment: @Bubbler I don't think the task is all that different for different charsets *except* when the charset happens to be very small, so let's say that *if* your language lacks a canonical char/str type, use an alphabet of your choice with at least 3 symbols. Unary is too easy, and binary has been done in a different question. And *if* your language has multiple canonical car/str types, you may choose.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

### `combine`

```
Ṿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn3/j056uHPGw50tD3fOPtalcLhdASzw/79SYlLyo4Y5SjoKSimpaUoA)

### `separate`

```
V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/s/9FJD3fOeLiz5eHO2ce6FA63K4AF/v@PftQwN1EHSCSBiGQQ8ahhTiyQnpOSmgbkAQA)

A boring, but short, solution. Uses Jelly's `repr` and `eval` atoms.

`Ṿ` is the right-inverse of `V`, meaning that `ṾV` (the Jelly way of composing 2 functions) returns the argument unchanged. Therefore, if passed `[A, B]`, `ṾV` will return `[A, B]`

The first program takes input as a pair `[A, B]` and unevals it. The second takes a string as input and evals it as a Jelly program

---

Just a quick precursor on strings and Jelly. Jelly does not like strings. At all. Internally, strings are just lists of characters to Jelly, and when outputting, Jelly will do all it can to "mash" everything together so that it doesn't look like it should. [An example](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zEpORHDXN1jP7/BwA) that you'd expect to output `['a', 'b', 'c', 2]`, or even `['abc', 2]`. As such, the Footers of the two programs above contain code to print the strings as-is, as lists of characters. Unfortunately, this can make them difficult to read.

But how do the programs work? Well, most of the work is done by the `combine` function. The `separate` function is simply "eval the argument as Jelly code".

### `Ṿ`

`Ṿ` is a weird atom, as Jelly atoms go. It's entire purpose is to act as the inverse to `V` (as a side note, if an character has an "underdot" below it in Jelly, it's likely to be the "inverse" to the atom without that underdot. For example, `O`/`Ọ` (ord/chr) or `Y`/`Ỵ` (join/split at newlines)) and the function it uses in the interpreter, `jelly_uneval`, is only used by one other atom, `Ṙ`, which just prints the same value as `Ṿ`.

However, `Ṿ` does a pretty good job at yielding some Jelly code that, when evaluated, yields it's argument. I won't break down into the exact details, but it's able to handle when string delimiters such as `“` are contained in the input, so is a pretty solid "uneval" atom, as these things go.

Comment: I don't think this is getting beaten in a while, so you win (also, you can apply the 75% bonus to get 0.5 score)

Comment: Can you explain how ```V``` (evaluate as a Jelly program) is able to 'produce two strings as a result' when given any single string as an argument, especially if the string isn't a valid Jelly program?  I [tried it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/s/9FJD3fOeLiz5eHO2ce6FA63K4AF/v9PSU0DAA) with the input string ```def``` and it didn't seem to work (but maybe I don't understand the TIO footer gubbins...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen `V` (in this case) takes the output of `Ṿ` as its argument. This will be a string containing at least one comma, where the two things either side of that comma are valid Jelly strings. For example `"“abc”,”d"`. It then evals this and returns a two element list containing the separated strings. The TIO Footer just prints the input and output of the function, but prints their "internal" representation as Jelly messes with string output quite a lot

Comment: I think this is invalid.  The spec says that 'separate' should 'produce two strins as a result' when 'invoked with a single string'.  It doesn't say that you can selectively choose only strings that were previously generated with your 'combine' function.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I read the question to mean that (because you don't *have* to handle a bike toon), that the input to `separate` would always be a `combine`d string. If the OP days otherwise, I'll happily delete/fix the answer

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>280</s> <s>202</s> <s>207</s> 196 (39+157) bytes

*Edit: +5 bytes to fix bug pointed-out by ChartZ Belatedly*

**Combine, 39 bytes**

```r
function(a,b,`-`=nchar)paste(-a,-b,a,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVDLbsMgELzzFZQTq0Akp7dKfEkUyYuDE1obbC9OQ5V/d3Ffyb230czsjHampYm99cGZpZ1Dk3wMEpVVta5NaM44wYCUnNSotFVFgYXcgBMmZ9jfxfXuV2RotpQmH05qNEjbY5xt56TrZGFp6HwqfsEFwL562R1AZUOFobmXz0qPAFD7tpYYsvS0DSgLdbvp/GRWywibSjVrggBFMhdcqXFfHTY7KHhFSucSwhgakc6Oj7Nv3rid4nvgbbwKZo14nfuBeLy4ia@WDj8yP8aTYOz3O4lwxxbYz0zrOA/CI/vd2GJo8lfHgCHRPxOXTw)

**Separate, 157 bytes**

```r
function(x,`-`=nchar,s=substring,q=as.double(el(strsplit(x," "))[1:2]),y=s(x,sum(3,-q)))`if`(any(is.na(q))||-y!=sum(q)+1,c(x,""),s(y,c(1,q[1]+2),c(q[1],-y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZDBbsMgEETvfAXlBApEcnqrxJdEkbwQnNDaYHuhDVX@3cVpm/Te22h29Ga084JuhBmS00uXg00@Bn6RrWp1sGeYJWrMBtPsw0lOGnB7jNn0jrueVxfH3qeaZ5QJsW9edgchi8bqYB74s1STEKL1XcshFO5xG4BX63pV5UmvkUlsGmlXAhMSeam6kdO@OWx2oupVSVUqZLFxMD44Te4zQZrHUDECJscVSGVkvQhCQLN0dnTK3r5RM8ePQLt4YcRo9pqHEWl8dzNdIz18FnqMJ0bI7zs4iIeutJ96fkPfD3/d78YOgi23jhFCwn8Sly8)

Not bijective and probably not shorter than a [Cantor-pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) based approach, but I like this because all the output is kind-of readable.

`combine` function calculates the lengths of strings `a` and `b`, encodes them as printable-ASCII, and prefixes them to the concatenated strings (with single space separators).
`separate` reads the characters before the first spaces, converts these to expected string-lengths, and splits-up the string accordingly.  If there are any problems (which will almost always occur if the string wasn't contructed using `combine`) it outputs a zero-length second string.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>111</s> 84 (41+43) bytes

*Edit: -27 bytes by simply filling the first output string of 'separate' with an error message if the input string wasn't generated by 'combine'.*

**Combine, 41 bytes**

```r
function(a,b)capture.output(dput(c(a,b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY6xbsMwDER3fQWhRRIQFGjHAvqAzB2bDJJMp25jUZEox87Pu4nQNt3bhTjwjnyX10CjHyLata8x8EBRu403wSWuGR@ocqqsu9sIzTFmLZhcdoxW/NzMJmjOi8bJHfXVLajZztfwRinz@vj8tBfCWclvCKc6hA/wmc4Repql8Fa@1zEVoAkz3CJHd1mgo4MU4pulnblrb8RX7VbpbvzemkbsXQxLYyQXufzDx62aEA7EUGhE2MlTJcaykw3yQqA6UrD9K2j9BA)

**Separate, 43 bytes**

```r
function(x)c(try(eval(parse(t=x))),'')[1:2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY69bsMwDIR3PQWhRSIQFGjHAn6AzB2bDJJMp25jUZEox87Lu437k@7tQhC8432Xl0LJZSfULF2NQXqOdsJgJc@WRne0H2ohK82EiBtj8Pn@8WG/BB58H6lRP09u4zG4JDXTHVdJVWx7HWFVEJVyjZYXglPtwxv4zOcIHU9a@Ua/1iEV4JEyXC1Hd5mh5YNW6ruedXjbPaqvAmv4Tfh9/SR2LoZ5ZSQXpfxD4taMBAcWKDwQ7PSpslDZ6RXyxGBaNrD9K2h5Bw)

Still not bijective, but a bit more competitive at the cost of being boring.  A loose port of ChartZ's Jelly [eval-uneval](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222635/95126) approach, but adjusted so that it will yield 2 strings as output with any string, not just with `eval`-able [R](https://www.r-project.org/) code.

`combine` function constructs a string expression representing [R](https://www.r-project.org/) vector containing the two strings `a` and `b`.
`separate` tries to evaluate its argument as [R](https://www.r-project.org/) code, and puts an error message into an output string if it fails.  It then appends an empty string, and returns the first two elements (so non-[R](https://www.r-project.org/) code, as well as valid [R](https://www.r-project.org/) code that would output more than one string-like return value, all finally output 2 strings).

Comment: Cool! So for instance `combine "fancy" "pants"` would be `"5 5 fancypants"`?

Comment: Embarassingly, the ```"fancy"``` ```"pants```" test case exposed an unforeseen bug!  It's fixed now (pleasingly for less bytes), and it indeed outputs more-or-less as you say: see the TIO links.

Comment: [This fails if one of the strings starts with a number and a space](https://tio.run/##pVBLbsMgFNxzCsoi4ikokt1dJU4SRcqD4ITWBptPG/fyLraTuvuyGs2H0Zswad8p64ycmux0st5xFAp6jMlwp28YOIJYgQIxa1M0PQZMRpLfzF04uZjEIDEeLj6r1nDT8phC7FubioNRBnCs3uoTiFHGrIpm3bUoMXf89VEyQHln25z5i40Hh4XY7VZpBCln6wD7Smz5UWheieFYnfY1FDwj8UzAzJTuUk0ISlbXNN0MHbLVH1QF/@Vo4@@MKMnec9dH6j9NWCwtfo/04q@MkOfBZYoNKyCP7ZbFNuEvu5Y26PS4dPToUvznj9MP)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly - Yikes!  You're right!  Fixed now (I think)... thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 44 bytes

```python
c=lambda *args:repr(args)
s=lambda x:eval(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pco7CoAwEEXR3lXINM6IhWAjAXdiM4migp8wEYmrj3@7d3nH7mu/zEVpJQRTjTzphuOUpXNKWit4LYrc93jVbjyip2BlmFcEhwY500QKsvgKYH0uqH2eAxFFrzOYOuTX3ZH89LHJqcMB)

Comment: The separate command does not seem to work on the string ```"abc"```: [try it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9k2JzE3KSVRQSuxKL3Yqii1oEgDxNLkKobJVFilliXmaFRo/i8oyswr0VAq1lBPTFLXtFLSUSjWUEpMSlbS1PwPAA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen you're right, I approached it as combine first, separate second. On the other hand I think it's reasonable for separate to accept only strings that the corresponding combine could have produced. Especially since `separate(combine(a,b))` MUST work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 59 (21+38) bytes -75% = score of 14.75

**Combine, 21 bytes:**

```
mcB128FS+ȯΣḣ+moB128mc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PzfZydDIwi1Y@8T6c4sf7lisnZsPEshN/v//f7RSYlKyko5SSmqaUiwA)

**Separate, 38 bytes**

```
momcB128₁B128mc
§e_o+₂¹-¹½S*→₂
÷2←√→*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc/N9nJ0MjiUVMjiMpN5jq0PDU@X/tRU9OhnbqHdh7aG6z1qG0SkMt1eLvRo7YJjzpmAflaFv///09MSk4BAA)

Bijective functions: each functions converts the input string(s) to a number by interpreting the codepoints in base-128, and then applies [Cantor pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to exchange between an integer and a pair of integers, before converting back to a string.
This can result in strings that contain unprintable characters, so the following testing links use modified versions that output the codepoints:

[separate to codepoints](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P9fJ0MjiUVMjiMpN5jq0PDU@X/tRU9OhnbqHdh7aG6z1qG0SkMt1eLvRo7YJjzpmAflaFv///09MSk4BAA) = converts "abcd" into the strings with codepoints [6,5] and [1,24,21]
[combine from codepoints](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PzfZydDIwi1Y@8T6c4sf7lisnQvi////PzraTMc0VifaUMfIRMfIMDYWAA) = converts that back to "abcd"

[combine to codepoints](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/38nQyMItWPvE@nOLH@5YrJ2bDxLITf7//3@0UmJSspKOUkpqmlIsAA) = converts strings "abc" and "def" to the string with codepoints [1,26,2,55,4,35,112]
[separate from codepoints](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc/N9nJ0MjiUVMjiOI6tDw1Pl/7UVPToZ26h3Ye2hus9ahtEpDLdXi70aO2CY86ZgH5Whb///@PNtQxMtMx0jE11THRMTbVMTQ0igUA) = converts that back to "abc", "def"

Alternatively, here ([combine](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc/WdvY0MnS3C1Y@8T6c4sf7lisnZsP5Ofm6xobJv///z9aKTEpWUlHKSU1TSkWAA) (27 bytes); [separate](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc/Nz9Z29jQydL8UVMjkMzN1zU2TOY6tDw1Pl/7UVPToZ26h3Ye2hus9ahtEpDLdXi70aO2CY86ZgH5Whb///@vqzLStlAAAA) (44 bytes) - score of 17.75) are versions with input/output restricted to the printable ASCII values 32-126.

Comment: Cool! Would this have any issues with `\x00`-prefixed strings?

Comment: @Quelklef - Good Q.  No.  Husk doesn't seem to be worried about null bytes in strings (I've just tested it!):  [Here](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzf5UcMyAwVDI/P//wE) is a program that creates a string with codepoints 0...127, and [here](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzf5UVMjF5BsWGagYGhk/v8/AA) is one that converts this back to codepoints (to check whether the null byte was somehow lost: it wasn't!).

Comment: @Quelklef - in any case (and to make testing easier), I've added a modified version that restricts input/output to printable ASCII from 32-126...

Comment: Cool! I'd have thought any "treat it as a number"-based solution would have trouble with leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 196 bytes

```python
import itertools as i
c=lambda a,b:(f:=chr(ord((sorted(a[-1:]+b[-1:])or'\x00')[-1])+1))+''.join(sum(i.zip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=f),start=()))
s=lambda x:(x[1::2].rstrip(x[0]),x[2::2].rstrip(x[0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BasMwEETv@Qrhi3ZrxVjppQj8Ja4psi03KrIldpXi9OcdpdBTT8MMw8xL93yN2@tbouPwa4qUhc@OcoyBhWXhT1MX7DrOVlg1GlhMN10JIs0AXNpuBtuftRnq8Vcwknzf21ZisQPWGrGWsvmKfgO@reCbH58@Qtw@HWcok2rxIXzbcHPdgoqzpdwBIp7473c3sPfamMvQEGfyqdh2QLX3l38hHon8loFhgmqsVGULjK4QlSCXqKQvDE9ALcsHHg8)

Slightly less boring than my other try, at the expense of being much longer. Unfortunately `c(s(x))` might not return exactly the same string, if a different fill value is specified than automatically would be determined.

## How it works

`c`(ombine) interleaves the two strings, with input `a` on the even positions and input `b` on the odd positions. As the strings need not be of equal lenght the shortest one is padded with fill character `f`. This is determined by taking the last character of both strings, sorting them and then taking the next codepoint as fillvalue. This fill value is then also prepended to the output to tell separate which characters to strip.

`s` simply takes every other character from the second character on, and strips all occurences of the fill value that's stored in the first character of the input, and then does the same for every other character from the third character on.

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: What will happen if either of the strings contains the last possible codepoint value in an alphabet?  Will the fill-value wrap-around, or will it crash?  And, if wrapping-around, what would happen if either string also already contains the first codepoint value?  Or, worst-case scenario, *all* codepoint values?

Comment: Luckily it doesn't remove all occurences of the fill value, but just the right padding. As we take only two strings as input there are exactly two codepoint values we need to consider, so there would be no problem if the rest of the string would be all codepoint values. Currently it will crash if either ends with the last possible codepoint value, as it does not wrap around. Knew that limitation but did not know a robust way to prevent collision with the other string.